# How to put something on the screen?

Tags: c++

I use **Ubuntu Studio 15.10** and I want to learn to program in **C++**.

I'm absolutely new into the **C++** programming world.

I wrote my first "code", with **gedit**.

In simple words, I want to put on the screen some text (like the old Basic: PRINT "Hello!").

So, I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
const double PI = atan(1) * 4;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    cout << "This is my first code with C++." << std::endl;
    cout << "Let's see what happen." << std::endl;
    cout << "2 * 3 = "; cout << 2 * 3 << std::endl;
    cout << "Constante pi = ";  cout << PI << std::endl;
    cout << "Seno de 45º = ";   cout << sin((45*PI)/180) << std::endl;
    cout << "Coseno de 30º = "; cout << cos((30*PI)/180) << std::endl;
    cout << "Tangente de 45º = ";   cout << tan((45*PI)/180) << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Then, I used **Codelite** to compile it and... I get a lot of files and folders.

The supposed executable file is called **main.cc**.

BUT... When I ask the system to run that file... Nothing happen!!!

I mean, there is not any text into any screen pane, any new window... Nothing, just Nothing!!!

What's wrong, here?

How can I get to see what I want to see into the screen?

Comment: The executable is not main.cc

Comment: What? So, which is the executable file? ???

Comment: You need to compile the code. Please look this up. Get a reasonable book on C++

Comment: codelite itself is an IDE, not a compiler. you'll need to set up compiler/linker to produce object code and eventually an executable from your sources.

Comment: Maybe we can go a little easier on OP? Yes it's not the greatest of questions, but consider how little you knew your first day (and the kinds of questions younger you might have asked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gcc/g++ to compile your code and run it, e.g ...

```
g++ main.cpp -o executable
```

Then you can run the program with

```
./executable
```

Don't use an IDE (Codelite) for practicing your first programming steps.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Now it works!!!

Comment: Just a curious: I used **g++** and then I got an **a.out** file (which is an executable file and it works what I want).  How can I get the **g++** compiler uses the same original *.cc name as final executable file name? ???

Comment: The -o flag defines the output name as i showed in my small example. You could write a shell script if you have a lot off source files to compile.

Answer (score -2):

about executable file formats ;

executable files are generated after your text based source code compilation according to system that the source code is being compiled.Every operating system has different executable file formats, `.cc` file format is not an executable, executable files can be in many different extentions.
In this link you can find some executable file formats for some systems
https://askubuntu.com/questions/156392/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-exe-file

Your program is executing and  than exiting, you should either pause the execution or get user input right before returning.

Comment: Thanks for your data!!!